# Unable to add patches via composer when we run "composer install" or "composer update"

Tags: 8, composer

I am facing an issue wherein I have added a single patch in my composer.json under "extras"

```
   "patches": {
            "drupal/field_validation": {
                "Declaration of (...)FieldValidationRuleAddForm::buildForm": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2941006-php-incompatible-buildform-signature.patch"
            },
            "drupal/ubercart": {
                "Not_yet_ported (missing)": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2020-05-28/ubercart_remove_not_yet_ported.patch"
            }
        },
        "enable-patching": true
```

After adding the patch under composer.json
I ran

```
composer install
```

but still it does not apply the patches listed.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was

```
composer require cweagans/composer-patches
```

we need to be sure that above package is included

After adding the above I was able to add patches via composer.json